# unsolved: Release a given number of pallets from a wait block with a dynamic event

Tags: anylogic

I would like to release a certain amount of pallets to the date from my database. So at 15 pm it should release 54 pallets. After this process ends another amount will be released to another time. When it comes to the wait block it doesn't release 54 pallets but 27. When I inject 20 pallets into my source block it releases 10 independent which amount (54) I wrote into the column,so always half of the number I get into my source block. Do you know why? The arrivals in the source block are also defined by a database. I tested it with a parameter with the number of pallets which I would like to release as well as with a database column called amount. Could it be the function in the dynamic event or the dynamic event trigger in main? After I solve this problem my project works so I hope you have an idea.

[dynamic_event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJBuj.png)

[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v80o5.png)

[dynamiceventtrigger_main_on_startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ6SG.png)

[dbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lqxf.png)

[process_during_simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MGiH.png)

Comment: check how many blocks you have on the wait block when you want to free 20 pallets... maybe only 10 pallets are on your wait block...

Comment: @Felipe I attached a screenshot from the process during the simulation